# Proving Vector Space with Scalar Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove a vector space with the following definitions:
$$[x,y]+[a,b]=[x+a+1,y+b]$$
$$r[x,y]=[rx+r-1,ry]$$

I'm working on the distributive law but I'm running into a problem. It's not coming out correctly for reason. Here's my work:

$$r([x,y]+[a,b])=r[x+a+1,y+b]=[r(x+a+1)+r-1,ry+rb]=[(rx+r)+(ra+r-1),ry+rb]$$

Shouldn't I be getting another $-1$ in there? (After the $rx+r$ term).

Comment: You could write out $r[x,y]+r[a,b]$ and verify it is equal to what you have so far and maybe see how it follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preservation of addition is given in terms of the vector space. So in fact,

$$r[x,y] + r[a,b] = [rx+r-1, ry] + [ra+r-1,rb] = [(rx+r-1) + (ra+r-1) + 1,ry+rb] = [(rx+r) + (ra+r-1), ry+rb]$$

as desired.

(I've posted this as an answer to avoid the odd typesetting issues I was seeing in the comments. )

Comment: So the extra one I was talking about doesn't need to be there?

Comment: Indeed you are. Once you reach the point you have, you can "reverse" the set of equivalences I have posted above to verify that the distributive law indeed holds.

Comment: ohhhhh! I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, observe that the correspondence $[a,b]\mapsto (a+1,b)$ is bijective and maps your addition and multiplication operations to the ordinary vector space operations on $\mathbb R^2$. So they *necessarily* satsify the vector space laws, simply because $\mathbb R^2$ does.

Comment: What does bijective mean? Sorry, I've only taken 1/2 semester of linear algebra so far.

Comment: @codedude: Bijective = injective (also knows as one-to-one) and surjective (also known as onto). In other words, a bijective map is one that has a well-defined inverse mapping. That's not linear algebra but just elementary function/set theory.

Comment: +1! I like this a lot. Avoids checking nine different axioms with one well chosen map. :)

Comment: @AWertheim: It probably isn't what the exercise author intended the student to do, though. (But almost certainly how he found these operations in the first place).

Comment: yeah I'd never heard of some of those terms before but I'll definitely look into them.